# SQL get avg of column for id 1, grouped by values in the same column for id 2

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, aggregate-functions

The same column in my table needs to be used for Averaging and Grouping By. The catch is that the id is different when implementing each function.

[image: Answers table]

My assignment questions are "What is your age" and "What is your gender".

I found the top 7 genders, these are: `'Male'`, `'Female'`, `'male'`, `'female'`, `'-1'`, `'Nonbinary'`, `'non-binary'`.

AnswerText contains the answers for each question. I want to get the Average age for each gender category in the list. I have done this:

```
SELECT AVG(AnswerText), Gender
FROM 
(
  SELECT AnswerText as Gender
  FROM Answer
  WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 2 
  AND Gender IN ('Male', 'Female', 'male', 'female', '-1', 'Nonbinary', 'non-binary')
)
WHERE Answer.QuestionID = 1
GROUP BY Gender
```

This is throwing error `no such column: AnswerText`.

How do I achieve this? The solution can either be in MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: `mysql <> sqlite`. I removed the conflicting tags, please tag only the one database you are using.

Comment: Please post your data as tabular text rather than images - which we can't properly read and copy/paste.

Comment: I edited your code to remove a carriage return that was inconsistent with your earlier prose & later error. Debug questions require a [mre]. That includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the Average age for each gender category in the list.

That's a self-join:

```
select a2.answertext as gender, avg(a1.answertext * 1.0) as avg_age
from answer a1
inner join answer a2 on a2.userid = a1.userid
where a1.questionid = 1 and a2.questionid = 2
group by a2.answertext
```